# Distinguishing and solving limits

Tags: calculus

Given: $`f(x)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{lcl}
-3x+8 &\mbox{ if }&x\geq 3\\
\frac{4}{2 -x} &\mbox{ if }&x<3\\
\end{array}
\right.`$

Find the limit if it exists. If the limit does not exist, distinguish between that goes infinity or (-) infinity and DNE. If f(x) continuous at x=3 and x=-1? Why?

Little help here? I dont understand the steps to completing this question and how to approach it.

1. [image]
   2.[image]

Comment: For $x<3$, do you mean $\frac{4}{2-x}$?

Comment: Yes not sure how to edit that

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $f$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)=f(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(a-h).
$$

Additionally, $f$ is going to go bad at $x=2$, because $\frac{4}{2-2}=\frac{4}{0}$ is not good. Clearly $f$ is not continuous at $2$. However, what are the limits as calculated above?

Edit: you can you use
$$
\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)=\lim_{h\to0}f(a-h)\;\text{ and }\;\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h).
$$

We're going to find $\lim_{x\to 3^+}f(x)$. We see that
$$
f(3+h)=-3(3+h)+8=-1+3h,
$$
so as $h\to0$, $f(3+h)\to -1$.

Comment: Oh shoot I didnt put in the rest of the question.

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: Not sure what your doing, mind showing me the steps and how to do for just one of the  two questions? Thanks

Comment: Sure, one second.